# View not loading in angular js app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4

This is my index.cshtml (view to which I re-direct from the server side controller)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" ng-app="AlumnusApp" class="no-js">
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.12/angular.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.12/angular-route.js"></script>
     <script src="~/Scripts/AlumnusScripts/AlumnusApp.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/AlumnusScripts/AlumnusController.js"></script>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>My AngularJS App</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div></div>
  <div ng-view></div>


</body>
</html>
```

My app and controller are as below

```js
'use strict';

// Declare app level module which depends on filters, and services
angular.module('AlumnusApp',['ngRoute']).
config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    debugger;
    $routeProvider.when('/Home', { templateUrl: '/Views/Home/Home.html', controller: 'HomeCtrl' });
    $routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: '/Home' });
}]);



/* Controllers */

angular.module('AlumnusApp')
  .controller('HomeCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
      alert('1');
  }])
```

However when I try to load the Home view it gives following error:-

```
http://localhost:2614/Views/Home/Home.html 404 (Not Found)
```

The path of the view is correct. Any suggestions?

Comment: try templateUrl: 'Views/Home/Home.html'

Answer (score 0):

try below templateUrl's

> templateUrl: 'Views/Home/Home.html'

OR

> templateUrl: '/Views/Home/Home.html'

OR

> templateUrl: '../Views/Home/Home.html'

Comment: None of the above seem to work. Could it be some problem that the file which has the view has not loaded? Can I check whether that file has loaded or not?

Comment: `404 for http://localhost:2614/Views/Home/Home.html` this error means home.html is not found, you will have to solve this first...

Comment: yes, but I cant understand why this file is not loading? Do I need to do any additional step to load this file? It should load by default if its in my project right?

Comment: if your templateurl is correct then it must load. but somehow the browser/host is not getting to the file path